# ldap3 печать значений attributes python

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory, ldap

Прошу проконсультировать как напечатать свойства атрибутов Active Directory:

интересуют только значение:

- displayName
- sAMAccountName
- department
- mail
- telephoneNumber
- Company
- physicalDeliveryOfficeName

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SUBTREE, ALL, NTLM
server = Server('hostname.domain.local', use_ssl=True, get_info=ALL)

conn = Connection(server, user='domain\test', password='12345_test', authentication=NTLM, auto_bind=True)

entry_list = conn.extend.standard.paged_search(search_base = 'dc=domain,dc=local',
                                               search_filter ='(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user) (!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)) (telephoneNumber=*) )',
                                               search_scope = SUBTREE,
                                               attributes=['displayName','sAMAccountName','department','mail','telephoneNumber','Company','physicalDeliveryOfficeName'],
                                               paged_size = 5,
                                               generator=False)

for i in entry_list:
    print(i)
```

Comment: А сейчас что вам выдаёт на печать?

Comment: сейчас очень много лишней информации.

Comment: пытался сделать так:  for i in entry_list:
    print(i['attributes']) получаю ошибку доступа

Comment: Ну покажите пример, что на печать сейчас выходит.

Comment: \xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8c,OU=\xd0\xa6\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd1\x80,OU=\xd0\xa3\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8f\xd1\x8e\xd1\x89\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f \xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f \xd0\xa1\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xba,OU=USERS,OU=USERS_DOMAIN,DC=domain,DC=local', 'dn': 'CN=Piskunova Natalya,OU=Казань,OU=Центр,OU=Управляющая компания Test,OU=USERS,OU=USERS_DOMAIN,DC=domain,DC=local', 'raw_attributes': {'telephoneNumb

Comment: а надо только свойства в атрибутах, название атрибутов не нужны

Comment: все символы не поместились

Comment: И всё-равно непонятно - там словарь или список, каким видом скобок всё начинается, вы их не показали?

Comment: Попробуйте `i['raw_attributes']`

Comment: 'attributes': {'telephoneNumber': '54621',....}

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

```
s = Server(ad_domain, use_ssl=True, port=636)  # Адрес домена, шифрование, порт
c = Connection(s, ad_admin, ad_password)


c.bind()   
c.search('ou=Офис, dc=DOMAIN, dc=local', '(&(objectCategory=Person)(cn={}))'.format(cn), SUBTREE,
             attributes=['sAMAccountName', 'givenName', 'sn', 'cn', 'whenCreated', 'lastLogon', 'pwdLastSet',
                         'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed', 'memberOf', 'ipPhone', 'lockoutTime'])

_ = c.entries
for ad_user in c.entries:
    group = []
    for i in range(len(ad_user['memberOf'])):
        group.append(ad_user['memberOf'][i].replace(',OU=Access Group,DC=DOMAIN,DC=local', '').
                     replace(',OU=Принтеры', '').replace(',OU=Приложения', '').replace('CN=', ''))
    
    name = ad_user['givenName']
    last = ad_user['sn']
    login = ad_user['sAMAccountName']
```